# Using Arcpy.UpdateCursor to delete adjacency rows based on a group ID

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have this sample file shown in the picture 1 below. it is a sample data set of a phone survey of drivers. I am trying to find out when those drivers started to drive.

My main goal is to build a loop to go through the rows and compare each row for each **unique trip id** and to check between those rows when the X (dbX field) and the Y (dbY field) have changed.
In my example (Picture 1) I have only two unique id trips - **55,56** but in my main data set i have alot more:

This is what I am trying to achieve in my goal data set:

1. **First row in goal data set (see picture two) will be based on**:
   For example in picture 1 - the X and Y values in the first row changes from OBJECTID =6, when those values change I want to delete all previous rows until row 5.

   **You can see an example of what I am trying to accomplish in picture 2.**
2. **Next values Until last rows** -
   For this values, I want to keep the first row where X and Y values changed and   delete all values of the same X and Y untill the last row before the next X,Y changes again.
   to make this step clear I want to keep only rows with OBJECTID = 6 AND 13 and (picture 2)

**Keep in my mind there are some Unique rows that Won't have more rows with the same X and Y  like the row with OBJECTID = 78.**

3. **Last row** - at end of each unique id I want to keep only the first row that is diffrent from the previous row in terms of x and Y :
   for example in picture 1 I want to keep only OBJECTID  = 149 and delete OBJECTID =1 150 AND 151

**Initial Data set picture 1:**

[image: initial data set]

This is the code I started writing but I think I am not on the right track

```
fcVertex ="Copy_Points_with_id_north_to_center_sample_55_57_copy"
fieldsvertex = ["dbX","dbY","Trip_ID","TimeStamp"]

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fcVertex,fieldsvertex,sql_clause=(None, 'ORDER BY Trip_ID ASC ; ORDER BY TimeStamp ASC')) as deleteCursorfixtime:
for row1 in deleteCursorfixtime:
    for row2 in deleteCursorfixtime:
        if row1[2] == row2[2]:
            if row1[0]== row2[0] and row1[1] == row2[1]:
                 if row1[3] != row2[3]:
                     deleteCursorfixtime.deleteRow()
```

**Goal Data set picture 2:**

[image: Goal data set]

Comment: I've never tried, but I'm pretty sure that you can't iterate twice over the same feature class at the same time. Instead, you would want to go through once and build a dictionary that tracks the first and last features associated with an XY pair; from that determine which features will be preserved. Then iterate again deleting the necessary features.